# How does the SetConsoleControlHandler function work? How do i inherit the current process's attributes to a child processes?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I need to write a function that uses Wnapi to open a process and closes it when CTRL+C is pressed.
I looked up the MSDN documentation about the functions `CreateProcess()` and `SetConsoleCtrlHandler()`. Now, I do understand how to properly use `CreateProcess()` and I understand that `SetConsoleCtrlHandler()` receives some sort of routine that handles the ctrl type. But even after looking up and digging through MSDN and previous StackOverflow questions I wasn't able to understand how can i link between these two functions and make my child process stop when i hit CTRL+C.

Comment: You can not. It is responsibility of the child process to `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` and exit upon receiving exit signal, or to implement some other kind of interruption method, such as handling WM_CLOSE.

Comment: No, you need GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent().  And prevent yourself from getting terminated, SetConsoleMode().  Odd requirement.

Comment: You can stop your child process using [`TerminateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess) in [`HandlerRoutine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler#parameters) function which called when `CTRL + C` is pressed.